# Object freeze literal object types

Tags: typescript

Given some frozen object:

```
const obj = Object.freeze({a: 1, b:2});
```

it's type is `Readonly<{a:number, b:number}>`, is there any way to define this so that it's type is `Readonly<{a:1, b:2}>` instead, without resorting to casting?

The reason I want this is because, I want to use the value types to narrow the input of another function, eg: `function foo(input: 1 | 2)`

Comment: `Object.freeze({a: 1, b: 2} as { a: 1; b: 2 })`?

Comment: I should of mentioned without casting, as I was wondering if there was a way to do it without repeating code. The object I has over 100 properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function l<T extends number>(p: T ): T { 
   return p;
}
const c = { a: l(1), b: l(2) };
// const fc: Readonly<{ a: 1; b: 2; }>
const fc = Object.freeze(c);
```

or

```
function lc<T extends number>(p: { [k: string]: T }) : { [k: string]: T } { 
    return p;
}
// const t1: { [k: string]: 1 | 2 | 3; }
const t1 = lc({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 });
```

Answer (score 1):

In the upcoming version of TypeScript (3.4) you will be able to do:

```
const obj = Object.freeze({ a: 1, b: 2 } as const); // { radonly a: 1, readonly b: 2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep value immutability you can simply define your Readonly class with a frozen decorator.

```
export function frozen(target: Function): void {
    Object.freeze(target);
    Object.freeze(target.prototype);
}
```

Comment: i want the type, because i want to use typeof Object.values(obj) to narrow the input of some other function

Comment: Have you considered using immutablejs ? It would fit for your need more than simply freeze the object type